# Simple VB code is not running

Tags: vb.net, mono, monodevelop, il, invalidprogramexception

I made a simple example in VB.net, compiled it, and run it:

```
Public Class Application
    Sub calc1()
        Dim sq as Integer
        'uncommenting this loop keeps it from compiling for some reason
        'For i as Integer = 1 to 1000
        '   sq = i*i
        'End For
        Console.WriteLine("calculated squares")
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim startTime as DateTime
        Dim endTime as DateTime
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello world!")
        startTime = Now
        calc1()
        endTime = Now
        Console.WriteLine(endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds.ToString("0.0000"))

    End Sub
End Class
```

Although it compiles fine, it gives an odd error when run:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in ThreadTest.Application:Main (): IL_0018: ldarg.0   


[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in ThreadTest.Application:Main (): IL_0018: ldarg.0
```

Comment: What's the compilation error when you uncomment the `For` loop?

Comment: Many errors, first ones are at `End For`. It says Expected `Sub`, Expected end of statement, Expected `End`, Expected end of statement. All lines after say Not valid as identifier.

Comment: Oh, it's not `End For`, it's `Next`. `While...End While`, `Do...Loop`, `For...Next`, `For Each...Next`.

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives an error when running.

Comment: There might be some problem in the argument, you are passing in        `Console.WriteLine(endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds.ToString("0.0000"))`

Answer (score 4):

The runtime error is because you're calling an instance function (calc1) from a shared function (Main).

Newer versions of vbnc (Mono's VB compiler) gives you this error:

```
test.vb (16,15) : error VBNC30369: Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.
```

This corrected code works:

```vb
Public Class Application
    Shared Sub calc1()
        Dim sq as Integer
        For i as Integer = 1 to 1000
            sq = i*i
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("calculated squares")
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim startTime as DateTime
        Dim endTime as DateTime
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello world!")
        startTime = Now
        calc1()
        endTime = Now
        Console.WriteLine(endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds.ToString("0.0000"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So, `shared` is equivalent to static? I wondered what that was for. What is the difference between Class and Module in .NET? (I'm more familiar with Java, I've rarely done VB.NET)

Comment: Yes, Shared is the same as static in C#/Java. A Module in VB is a class where all the members are Shared (the same as a static class in C#).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `End For` in your commented loop, you need to use `Next`.

The other part of it is a *compiler* error, and not your fault. The mono vb compiler still needs some work. If I had to guess, I'd say the problem here is either that it sees your method does no real work and tries to make a bad optimization with your two uses of Datetime.Now, or that it's using the wrong overload for the DateTime.Subtract call... but again, those are just guesses.

What you should do, though, is use a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class rather than Datetime values.

Answer (score 1):

```
Main function is required in file like as below :

     Public Class Application
            Public Shared Sub calc1()
                Dim sq As Integer
                'uncommenting this loop keeps it from compiling for some reason
                'For i as Integer = 1 to 1000
                '   sq = i*i
                'End For
                Console.WriteLine("calculated squares")
            End Sub
        End Class

        Sub Main()
            Dim startTime As DateTime
            Dim endTime As DateTime
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello world!")
            startTime = Now
            Application.calc1()
            endTime = Now
            Console.WriteLine(endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds.ToString("0.0000"))
            Dim inputFromConsole As String
            Dim outputToConsole As String
            Console.WriteLine("Type in a sentence and hit Enter:")
            inputFromConsole = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine(outputToConsole)


        End Sub
```